# BindingFailure on assembly PresentationFramework.Aero2

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

My WPF application, named Odyssey, throws an exception while starting, more specific: when creating a new window.

> Additional Information: The assembly with display name 'PresentationFramework.Aero2' failed >to load in the 'Load' binding context of the AppDomain with ID 1. The cause of the failure >was: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly >'PresentationFramework.Aero2, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, >PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file >specified.

The strange thing is that when I run the application with the "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" unchecked - this exception is thrown. When running it while the "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" is checked - it works like expected since it loads 'PresentationFramework.Aero'.

Since the application is trying to load the 'PresentationFramework.Aero2', the application itself fails with not showing any images.

I tried to create a new solution and then it worked, but only if I have a different name on the solution! I backed up Odyssey and then deleted it, removed .Net 4.5 and Visual Studio 2012. I re-installed .Net 4.5 and Visual Studio 2012, but when I create a new solution named Odyssey, it still tries to load 'PresentationFramework.Aero2', but not for the other solutions I have made.

Anybody now a fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this myself. I ended up with deleting all the references to Odyssey in the windows registry in pure frustration and it ended up working!

Answer (score 0):

After move application from one PC to another, I also got error message: Additional Information: The assembly with display name 'PresentationUI.Aero2' failed to load in the 'Load' binding context of the AppDomain with ID 1.
I resolve this problem by deleting .suo file and it works.

Comment: Can you add some detail, like where is the .suo file, what are some consequences of removing it (beside fixing the exception), etc.